# Intern functional test: mock datetime

Tags: intern

I'm new to [intern](https://github.com/theintern) test. I would like to know can I mock datetime with intern functional testing (example: test run 3 days ahead of today).

Answer (score 1):

lolex (https://github.com/sinonjs/lolex) is used by sinon.js to mock Date.

It simply replaces Date with its own implementation (https://github.com/sinonjs/lolex/blob/master/lolex.js#L477-L479).

Comment: Thanks for the link, unfortunately I'm not sure how I would use it in the intern test scripts. Any idea?